# Not able to cancel huawei IAP subscription

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-purchase, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-iap

I was trying for server side Canceled api of IAP but I am not able to cancel the subscription using this api. Everytime I am clicking cancel i am getting this error :
responseCode:"6","responseMessage":"900030-authorization format invalid"

and the API which I am using is this:
https://subscr-dra.iap.hicloud.com/sub/applications/v2/purchases/stop

Can anybody help me with this I am stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Check the format of the token you are putting in header as authorization.

Code:

```
let oriString = 'APPAT:' + app_level_access_token;

let authorizationToken = new Buffer.from(oriString).toString('base64'); // converting the token into Base64.
```

Now this `authorizationToken`, you can use it in the header.

Answer (score 0):

The Extension of AT File is incorrect.

> Authentication information is specified based on the request header.
> The details are as follows: App-level access token: Authorization:
> Basic Base64(APPAT:atvalue)
>
> - Example: The app-level access token is thisIsAppAtValue, then APPAT:atvalue is APPAT:thisIsAppAtValue. Therefore, replace
>   APPAT:atvalue in Base64(APPAT:atvalue) with APPAT:thisIsAppAtValue,
>   and value QVBQQVQ6dGhpc0lzQXBwQXRWYWx1ZQ== is obtained. The value of
>   Authorization in the request header is as follows: Basic
>   QVBQQVQ6dGhpc0lzQXBwQXRWYWx1ZQ==

The sample code is as follows:

```
  /* Build Authorization in Header
     *
     * @param appAt app AccessToken
     * @return headers
     */
    public static Map<String, String> buildAuthorization(String appAt) {
        String oriString = MessageFormat.format("APPAT:{0}", appAt);
        String authorization =
            MessageFormat.format("Basic {0}", Base64.encodeBase64String(oriString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Authorization", authorization);
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        return headers;
}
```

HMS In-App Purchases(IAP) Severdemo on [Github](https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-iap-serverdemo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/huawei/iap/demo/AtDemo.java).

Answer (score 0):

The error code that you received – 900030 means your signature verification data format is invalid. The possible causes are:
•   The token in the request header is not encrypted in Base64 mode.
•   The character string APPAT is not appended to the beginning of the access token for authorization. The correct access token is in the format of APPAT:thisIsAppAtVaule.

You can read about this error code [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/faq-0000001050033126)

Please make sure that your request follow the format specified in this [document](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/api-common-statement-0000001050986127-V5)

If you still receive the same error, kindly post your request data format here.